# How to mock class attributes with supplied user value?

Tags: python, mocking, pytest, patch

I would like to mock my class attribute under test.

The class is as follows:

```
import path.to.some.other.class.OtherClass
class ClassToTest:
   def __init__(self, some_path):
    self._attribute_to_test = OtherClass(some_other_path)
    
    #rest of the class details
    ..
```

Unit Test that I tried to write is as follows (but does not work as expected):

```
with patch("path.to.some.other.class.OtherClass") as _mock:
    instance = _mock.return_value
    ClassToTest._attribute_to_test = instance
```

Now when I try to instantiate the ClassToTest the attribute `attribute_to_test` does not mock.

Comment: `_attribute_to_test` seems to be an instance attribute, not a class attribute, so this won't work. Anyway, setting the attribute explicitely shold not be needed - if you correctly mock `OtherClass`, it shall be initialized with the mock. Instead, you have to set `return_value` to the needed value.

Comment: I tried mocking the `OtherClass`with ``_mock.return_value = some_value ``
But while debugging through ClassToTest later, the step `OtherClass(some_other_path)` does not show Mock type, but still sticks to its original notation. 
I think I am really not understanding the mock concept on how to mock objects then

Comment: You may just mock the wrong object, check [where to patch](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#id6).